# LC-3 Tracking LDI Through Memory

Tags: assembly, lc3

An assembly language program contains the following two instructions. The assembler puts the translated version of the LDI instruction that follows into location x3025 of the object module. After assembly is complete, what is in location x3025?

```
PLACE  .FILL  x45A7
       LDI    R3, PLACE
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is x45A7.
It's x45A7 because that's the value the pseudo-op .fill used.
The reason the LDI chose to load the .fill value is because of the the label PLACE which told it that was the location to get the value.